# GMRES implementations

Tags: gmres, libraries

I am looking for simple [GMRES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_minimal_residual_method) implementations. Unfortunately, I have a few requirements:

- should be C or Fortran, Fortran preferred
- needs a license that permits inclusion in an MIT/BSD licensed package
- needs to deal with complex data

So far, the "[templates](http://www.netlib.org/templates/)" code on netlib seemed to fit well. However, it doesn't deal with complex data (although I think changing a few declarations from real to complex could fix that), and also it obviously implements operations better left to BLAS (I think e.g. [this code's](http://www.netlib.org/templates/double//GMRESREVCOM.f) Givens rotations that'd probably better be `drot()` calls). Another alternative, PETSc, seems overkill.

I am looking forward to your suggestions. Thank you!

Comment: What sort of problem are you solving?  Do you already have effective preconditioners or is that something you'll need to experiment with?  (A GMRES implementation is not a big deal, but usually preconditioning is a lot more subtle and most people would benefit a library.)

Comment: Actually I'm not yet at the point of really needing GMRES (so far, I'm using a completely different method for my computations). It's mostly playing around so far. I can't really say anything about the matrices I'll have to deal with. With my current method, the matrices are very well conditioned, I don't really see why this would change with a different method applied to larger problems (meaning larger matrices which made GMRES attractive). Do you think it's worth having a shot at GMRES myself?

Comment: I am biased (PETSc developer), but I would use PETSc for your experiments, especially if you don't already have a lot of experience with which methods are most effective for your problem. The range of Krylov methods, monitoring in different norms, eigenvalue estimation, and a suite of preconditioning choices takes orders of magnitude more effort than just a GMRES implementation, but is tremendously useful to find the most effective methods for your problem.